# IAM role with AWS SDK for php not working

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I am trying to get details of all the EC2 instances running on AWS using AWS SDK for PHP. For this, I am using an IAM role which I have already attached to another instance on which AWS SDK is running.

Here is my code :

```
require_once 'sdk.class.php';


$ec2 = new AmazonEC2(array(
  'default_cache_config' => '/tmp/secure-dir'
));

$result = $ec2->describe_instances();



$response = json_encode($result);
```

I have created /tmp/secure-dir with full permissions. But when I execute the above script, it returns `"Auth Failure"`.

However, I am able to fetch the details of all the servers using `AWS CLI.`
Is there something I am missing ?

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Is this code running on an EC2 instance, and has *this* instance had its IAM role set?

Comment: Yes.. I have attached the specified IAM role with the instance.